# How do I move my c-lightning node to a different machine without closing my channels?

Tags: core-lightning, server

If I wanted to move my c-lightning node to an other machine, is there a way to do that (and how)? Specifically, without changing my node key or closing my channels?

This question was asked by plant-boy on IRC.

Answer (score 4):

This question was answered by Christian Decker on IRC.

> Yes, it's a bit tricky, because you never want to start the old copy
> once you started the new one, but absolutely doable. 1) stop the old
> node, 2) rename the `.lightning` directory so you can't accidentally
> restart the old node (maybe verify that starting will create a new
> node), 3) copy the renamed `.lightning` to new host in the place where
> you'll be running from, and 4) point lightningd to the copied
> directory and start it.
>
> I'd also delete any copy remaining on the old host for safety
> (starting that one may lead to loss of funds). While you're at it,
> make a backup of `hsm_secret` files in the directory (those are static
> and safe to copy)

Comment: `starting that one may lead to loss of funds` Interesting. Isn't that a bug and something that should/can be fixed?

Comment: No, more a footgun than a bug. Like accidentally broadcasting a revoked state could lead to you being punished and losing all your funds in the channel. Of course in an ideal world these footguns wouldn't exist but we don't know how to magic them away in the Lightning protocol (and it may well be impossible without designing a completely different protocol).

Comment: I guess we are talking definitions/semantics. I would describe a footgun as something that is addressed with user guidance, user docs etc but it is well known and understood in the protocol. I would describe a bug as something that is discovered out of the blue and needs squashing asap (ie there is no reason for it to exist). Of course in consensus systems some bugs (like the CHECKMULTISIG OP_0 bug) can't be squashed without a hard fork so the definitions do get confusing and create grey areas.

Comment: Correct, losing any state transition is deadly in the LN protocol, which is why we came up with a more forgiving protocol with eltoo. The protocol itself makes backups and restores pretty dangerous (and this migration is pretty much just a backup + restore), because even missing a single update may lead to loss of funds (and that's true for all implementations).

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Magic? Impossible? Not sure if I agree with that part. I will experiment and see if this can be used by attackers. Will share if I find anything interesting with some possible solutions/workarounds.

Comment: @Prayank: With onchain funds you can't lose your private key and you can't leak your private key to an attacker. Is that a bug? No it is a well understood footgun and limitation of cryptographic protocols. SImilarly Lightning requires you to monitor the chain (stay online) and not to accidentally broadcast a revoked state. Another well understood footgun and limitation of Lightning. Pre-eltoo if a malicious channel counterparty can trick you into broadcasting a revoked state you can lose your funds in the channel. No experimentation needed, it is a known footgun.

Comment: There is a difference between losing private key and old state running with new state. You can call it footgun or something else. Experiment is required because 1. I mostly contribute in projects that use on-chain 2. Know if this _footgun_ can help attackers remotely or in combination with other known issues